# Salesforce Experience Cloud - Group Pages Missing

Tags: community, chatter-groups, experience-cloud

I have an Experience Cloud site using the Customer Account Portal theme. For some reason, the standard Group List and Group Detail pages are missing. I set up navigation to go to the Group object and default to the Active Groups list. When I click on a group name, it opens the group in the standard Record Detail page instead of the Group Detail page. This is a problem because the Record Detail page doesn't have the Group component that shows the feed. Instead, the page just shows the typical banner, detail, and related lists. I can't edit the standard Record Detail page to have the Group component because this page is being used by other objects in the site.

Does anyone know why the standard Group pages are missing from my site and/or how to resolve this problem? I can't just create a custom Group page because the link in the record list goes to the record detail page.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce told me to create a new Record page for the Groups object, and then the link to the Groups page would go there instead of the generic record page. This solved the problem and allowed me to customize the layout for Groups without impacting the other record pages.